# How to get the number of duplicates in a list of coordinates as tuples with isclose()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of coordinates as tuples:

```
  listoc = ['(-87.5, -960.8147117258)', 
     '(91.3147117258, -960.8147117258)', 
     '(85.5, 99.50000000000011)', 
     '(85.5, -966.8147117258)', 
     '(91.3147117258, -968.8147117258)', 
     '(87.5, -968.8147117258)', 
     '(93.3147117258, -966.8147145072)', 
     '(93.3147117258, -962.8147117258)', 
     '(-87.5, -968.8147117258)', 
     '(-91.3147117258, -155.00000000000009)', 
     '(-85.5, -966.8147145204)', 
     '(-85.5, -962.8147117258)', 
     '(-91.3147117258, -155.0)',
     '(-87.5, -960.8147117258)', 
     '(-93.3147117258, -962.8147089444)', 
     '(85.500000071, 99.50)', 
     '(-73.0, -517.5)']
```

With the use of `math.isclose()` I want to get the number of duplicates.

I tried this without `isclose()`, because I don't know how:

```
    for cord in listoc:
        number_cc += listoc.count(cord)

    print('Number of duplicates: '+ str(number_cc))
```

The output:

> Number of duplicates: 19

But it should be:

> Number of duplicates: 3

I'm using `python3.6`

Comment: You need to remove the parentheses first

Comment: I found only 1 duplicate which is `'(-87.5, -960.8147117258)',`

Comment: Are you looking to see if what coordinates are close to each other or are you looking to see if there are coordinates where the lat is close to the long?

Comment: @jkrae finished the exercise, answer number 2, result is 3, (got problem with code, pasted without changing cordx/2x to cordy/2y) now it works. Can I please have my brownie points? need to overcame no more question banning, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :

```
for cord in listoc:
        number_cc += listoc.count(cord) - 1  ### here the difference

print('Number of duplicates: '+ str(number_cc/2)) ### here the difference
```

otherwise you'll get at least the number of element of the listoc, because cord it's always at least once inside the list and you count twice the same couple of numbers

As per your title  if you want to use math.isclose(), I ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jun 20 12:34:52 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054705/how-to-get-the-number-of-duplicates-in-a-list-of-coordinates-as-tuples-with-iscl

"""

import math

import itertools



listoc = ['(-87.5, -960.8147117258)', 
     '(91.3147117258, -960.8147117258)', 
     '(85.5, 99.50000000000011)', 
     '(85.5, -966.8147117258)', 
     '(91.3147117258, -968.8147117258)', 
     '(87.5, -968.8147117258)', 
     '(93.3147117258, -966.8147145072)', 
     '(93.3147117258, -962.8147117258)', 
     '(-87.5, -968.8147117258)', 
     '(-91.3147117258, -155.00000000000009)', 
     '(-85.5, -966.8147145204)', 
     '(-85.5, -962.8147117258)', 
     '(-91.3147117258, -155.0)',
     '(-87.5, -960.8147117258)', 
     '(-93.3147117258, -962.8147089444)', 
     '(85.500000071, 99.50)', 
     '(-73.0, -517.5)']

number_cc = 0
for cord, cord2 in itertools.combinations(listoc, 2):
    

        cordx, cordy = cord.split(',')[0].strip('('), cord.split(',')[1].strip(')')
        cord2x, cord2y = cord2.split(',')[0].strip('('), cord2.split(',')[1].strip(')')
        if math.isclose(float(cordx),float(cord2x)) and math.isclose(float(cordy),float(cord2y)):
            
            number_cc +=1  
            print('ok #: ' , number_cc,' index : ',listoc.index(cord),cord,' index : ',  listoc.index(cord2),cord2)
        else:
            pass
            
print(number_cc)
```

which gives as output:

```
ok #:  1  index :  0 (-87.5, -960.8147117258)  index :  0 (-87.5, -960.8147117258)
ok #:  2  index :  2 (85.5, 99.50000000000011)  index :  15 (85.500000071, 99.50)
ok #:  3  index :  9 (-91.3147117258, -155.00000000000009)  index :  12 (-91.3147117258, -155.0)
3
```

So 3 duplicates, be carefull because here:

```
ok #:  1  index :  0 (-87.5, -960.8147117258)  index :  0 (-87.5, -960.8147117258)
```

second index 0 should be 13 but list.index(x) return first index having x as value, it is actually the only x == y in your list

you can play with:

`math.isclose(a, b, rel_tol, abs_tol)`

where:

```
a   Required. The first value to check for closeness

b   Required. The second value to check for closeness

rel_tol = value     Optional. The relative tolerance. It is the maximum allowed difference between value a and b. Default value is 1e-09

abs_tol = value     Optional. The minimum absolute tolerance. It is used to compare values near 0. The value must be at least 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

listoc = ['(-87.5, -960.8147117258)',
 '(91.3147117258, -960.8147117258)',
 '(85.5, 99.50000000000011)',
 '(85.5, -966.8147117258)',
 '(91.3147117258, -968.8147117258)',
 '(87.5, -968.8147117258)',
 '(93.3147117258, -966.8147145072)',
 '(93.3147117258, -962.8147117258)',
 '(-87.5, -968.8147117258)',
 '(-91.3147117258, -155.00000000000009)',
 '(-85.5, -966.8147145204)',
 '(-85.5, -962.8147117258)',
 '(-91.3147117258, -155.0)',
 '(-87.5, -960.8147117258)',
 '(-93.3147117258, -962.8147089444)',
 '(85.500000071, 99.50)',
 '(-73.0, -517.5)']

print([(item, count) for item, count in collections.Counter(listoc).items() if count > 1])
```